# Race condition in Playwright .NET during click-to-navigate with WaitForURLAsync

Tags: c#, playwright, race-condition, playwright-dotnet

I'm using Playwright with the **.NET bindings**.

There used to be a problem where causing a navigation via a click could lead to a race condition, i.e.:

```cs
await page.ClickAsync(".foo");         // indirectly causes a navigation
await page.WaitForNavigationAsync();   // race condition; times out
```

That was a [problem inherited](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3338#issuecomment-426584706) from Puppeteer (of which Playwright is a fork) and the same workaround was recommended (even though it should work in .NET, this pattern was needed due to the cs-js interop):

```cs
var task = page.WaitForNavigationAsync();
await page.ClickAsync(".foo");
await task;
```

Since then Playwright introduced `WaitForURLAsync` [feature](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url) which was supposed to eliminate that problem:

```cs
await page.ClickAsync(".foo");
await page.WaitForURLAsync();
```

I assume that works for others. But I'm using the .NET bindings, and I see this issue when scraping a SPA; when I use the old workaround, the problems disappear:

```cs
var task = page.WaitForURLAsync();
await page.ClickAsync(".foo");
await task;
```

I can't post a repro for a specific site as it's confidential. But I wonder whether this new .NET method was implemented to have the same behaviour as the Node version? Has anyone else encountered this problem, and what remedy did you take?

Answer (score 0):

You can user wait for an event in below fashion as explained [here and it helps](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/events#waiting-for-event)

```
var waitForRequestTask = page.WaitForRequestAsync("**/*logo*.png");
await page.ClickAsync(".foo");
var request = await waitForRequestTask;
```

Alternatively expect can be used, then it will wait for it before moving forward

```
Expect(Page.locator("Element on target page")).ToBeVisibleAsync()
```